# react-native with xcode simulator has very slow alerts

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

In general, the xcode simulator works very well with react-native. For example, using live reload, changes made to the code are reflected in less than a second. However if I do Cmd+d in the simulator to bring up Debug menu, the menu comes up very quickly, but I cannot click any option for something like 20 seconds.  The same happens with a javascript alert, the alert comes up quickly but it takes 10 to 20 seconds to be able to dismiss it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Maybe you are pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by mistake? This command triggers 'slow animations', so all animations in the simulator happens very slowly

Comment: I thought my computer couldn't handle the simulator

Comment: Lol me too! Thanks for this!

Comment: This reminds me of the old shift + click mac trick. Because.. people just love watching things in slow motion

Comment: Thanks Kaleb for this. I thought I had a memory leak. Why would anyone want to turn this on?

Comment: So useful! Before your solution, I've even considered not using Alert because of this.